# macOS Desktop-App with SwiftUI: How to open window from menubar (MenuBarExtra), and show it on top?

Tags: swift, cocoa, swiftui

I have a menubar icon, and when I click on it, I want a new window to be opened. This part works. But the window is sometimes covered by other windows. How do I set the window to be on top of other windows?

I'd like to keep using as much as possible from SwiftUI.

Here's what I tried so far:

```
import SwiftData
import SwiftUI

@main
struct ScreenOnTimeApp: App {
    @Environment(\.dismissWindow) private var dismissWindow
    @Environment(\.openWindow) private var openWindow

    var body: some Scene {
        Window("State changes", id: "another-window-id") {
            PowerChangesWindow().onAppear {
                dismissWindow(id: "another-window-id")
            }
        }

        Window("foobar", id: "foobar") {
            VStack {
                Text("Some Text ...")
            }
            .frame(width: 350, height: 250)
        }

        MenuBarExtra("1", systemImage: "1.circle") {
            Button("One") {
                // i want the window to be always above other windows...
                dismissWindow(id: "foobar")
                openWindow(id: "foobar")
            }
            Button("Two") {
                NSApp.activate(ignoringOtherApps: true)
                dismissWindow(id: "another-window-id")
                openWindow(id: "another-window-id")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Clicking the "Two" menu item *does* bring "another-window-id" to front.